# Javascript: How to refresh the parent window from the child window

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9

The problem is that `window.opener` does not work in this case. The reason is because it is null. It is null because the child window will go through a few urls before the javascript can run. So without the original child's DOM (ie: access to `window.opener`), how can I refresh the parent page?

Comment: I think [phpmyadmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php) was doing something like that. In the sql query window.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think that would be possible with JavaScript only. The only solution I can think of is using Ajax to poll to an server-side page that indicates if the page has to be refreshed.

Answer (score 0):

You can (kinda):

1. Hold a ref to the child in the parent.
2. wait for a while so the child is on the final URL
3. use the window ref from (1) to call a
   function like registerParent(parentWindow) that takes the window
   ref.
4. Store that somewhere and use as window.opener.

This isn't reliable, but it might work well enough. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should consider different approach, e.g. instead of regular calls you could do ajax in child window. That would preserve reference to parent window.  Or maybe you should drop separate window concept altogether and display everything in one window using ext or jquery ui UI elements. Ext example: http://www.danvega.org/examples/extwindow/basicwindow.cfm, jQuery UI example: http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/